Finding all changes to a block of text with git
I have a text file that I'd like to track changes with. It's a file that stores values (as well as strings and arrays) and has the following format for its entries:
NAME: some_name
  UNIT: some_unit
  ...
  VALUE: 10
  ...
END

I've setup a repository to track changes on this file BUT now I would like to understand the change history of an entry like some_name.
I think this would be similar to understanding the change history of a function, where the user would like to understand the history of the entire function between various revisions.
I've tried the method described here with several attempts like:
git log -L '\bsome_name\b', '\bEND\b':config.txt

fatal: invalid object name '\bEND\b'.

also from here I've tried:
git log -p | grep '(\bsome_name\b)(.|\s)*?(\bEND\b)'

...which returns nothing.
UPDATE 20240818:
Further attempts:

Defined a custom hunk-header and tried using git log -L:some_name:config.txt.  This does work for some entries but does not find other entries, similar to git log -L'/some_name/','/END/':config.txt
using git log -p -W >> test.txt I can manually inspect the output and see that the entries that are not found by the above methods are indeed there.

The answer provided by @phd should work and yet it ignores some entries.

'-L/^NAME: some_name$/,/^END$/:config.txt', also see here, It's hard to help you understand what's failing when you don't show what's failing.

The syntax is git log -L/start_re/,/end_re/:file, no spaces inside. Git uses POSIX regex syntax that doesn't support \b word boundary. Try this:
git log -L'/some_name/','/END/':config.txt


with this i get fatal: -L parameter 'some_name' starting at line 1: No match

@jayveesea Just tried — works for me. You need to show something real, not just error message. [mcve], please.

not sure how to provide an mre here, unfortunately this is not on github nor open source to be cloned, so complete and reproducible is a challenge.  that said, i think your hint on POSIX regex may lead somewhere.

@jayveesea Create a small public repo and push it to GitHub for us to clone. One small file, a few commits, and an example of failed git log -L command.

i tried to get the history on a different entry and it worked!  as of now this will work for some entries but not others.

also created a test repo and this kinda works but starts to break when the entry is moved around.  many changes were made to some_name but it only detects a recent one now.

@jayveesea Nice test, thanks! git log -L '/FESTWERT valueParameter/,/END/':config.txt gives me 2 commits, b54a9c7 and ae2fcf2. git log -L '/FESTWERT some_name/,/END/':config.txt gives me just 1 commit, perhaps because the section is removed and restored.

git log -L '/FESTWERT some_name/,/END/':config.txt @~ (that is, starting from the last but one commit and going back to the initial commit) gives me 5 commits: f007f76, b7435e7, ba9374d, f9b4f1e, 590aef3.

thanks so much your help here. going back one rev and then doing the search is getting closer but my actual file has over a thousand entries and stuff is getting added or removed on a regular basis (which i have no control over)... it would be difficult if i can't just be at the current rev and search for all changes.

Look up the line numbers of the first line and the last line of the block of text you want to look at in the currently checked-out file. Then:
git log -L123,157:config.txt

(Obviously, replace the numbers by those that you found.) Note that there are no blanks in the command line argument.

thx for info, unfortunately this config file has entries that are occasionally removed or added, so position varies

@jayveesea That does not matter, because Git knows about the changes. Just pick the line numbers in the file that is currently checked out.

it does kinda work but when there's a major change in position it looses track and starts looking at the wrong thing.  if there wasn't such drastic changes to my config file this would work nicely.  thx!
